# Spring security OAuth stackoverflowException

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I would like to use Spring security with OAuth and JWT tokens.
My current configurations are:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
protected static class ResourceServer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off   
        http.anonymous().disable()
        .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()) // handle access denied in general (for example comming from @PreAuthorization
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPointBean()) // handle authentication exceptions for unauthorized calls.
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            // only allow this three endpoint to NOT be authenticated.
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/authenticate").permitAll()
             .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/users/inviationCode/{code}").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(filterBean(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
            .requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/**")))
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().expressionHandler(new OAuth2WebSecurityExpressionHandler())
            .and()
        .csrf().disable(); // for chrome/FF plugins to work. for now we shouldn't face any problem since there is no point that JS can be injected into our page...
        // @formatter:on
    }
    
    @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        return new AccessDeniedExceptionHandler();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPointBean() {
        return new UnauthorizedEntryPoint();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    GenericFilterBean filterBean() {
        return new XAuthTokenFilter();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    
    @Bean(name="userAuthenticationManager")
    public UserAuthenticationService userAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new UserAuthenticationService();
    }

}


@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restDataSource")
    private BasicDataSource restDataSource;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')").checkTokenAccess(
                "hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("test")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .secret("secret");
    }

  }
}
```

Those configurations are based on the official spring [github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/tests/annotation/jwt)
The problem I am facing now, is that whenever I try to obtain a token using this url:

> http://myapplication.com/test/oauth/token?grant_type=password

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger.isDebugEnabled(Jdk14Logger.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:144)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:427)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:427)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$AuthenticationManagerDelegator.authenticate(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:427)
at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:177)
```

This seems like a loop in the authentication process but to be honest I can find the root of it.
The flow I would like to use is the following:

- User asks for a token passing user name, password and client (probably in base64). (METHOD POST)
- User is being authenticated.
- User is returned a JWT token.
- User carries the token in the header.

Can someone advice on the appropriate configurations?

Best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem, it was specific to the authentication manager.
This is the working configuration for me:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableResourceServer
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("restDataSource")
    private DataSource datasource;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        return new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomJwtTokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new CustomJwtTokenStore();
    }

//      @Bean
//      public JdbcTokenStore tokenStore() {
//          return new JdbcTokenStore(datasource);
//      }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.tokenKeyAccess("isAnonymous() || hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')").checkTokenAccess(
                "hasAuthority('ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT')");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).tokenStore(tokenStore()).accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("my-trusted-client")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60)
        .and()
            .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "trust")
                .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value")
        .and()
            .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .secret("secret");
    }

}
}
```

with the security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

@Autowired
private GenericFilterBean filter;


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**", "/images/**", "/oauth/uncache_approvals", "/oauth/cache_approvals");
}

@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userAuthenticationManager()).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .sessionManagement()
      .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
        .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler) // handle access denied in general (for example comming from @PreAuthorization
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint) // handle authentication exceptions for unauthorized calls.
    .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/xxx/**").fullyAuthenticated()
        .antMatchers("/xxx/**").fullyAuthenticated()
        .antMatchers("/xxx/**").fullyAuthenticated()
     .and()
       .csrf().disable();;
}

@Bean
@Autowired
ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> loggerBean() {
    return new org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
    return new AccessDeniedExceptionHandler();
}

@Bean
@Autowired
AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPointBean() {
    return new UnauthorizedEntryPoint();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean(name="userAuthenticationManager")
public UserDetailsService userAuthenticationManager() throws Exception {
    return new UserServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public UserService userService() {
    return new UserServiceImpl();
}   
}
```

Comment: And here is a more detailed gist for that https://gist.github.com/maxsap/da154f99a2dbb414471a