# jQuery ajax equivalent of curl command - CORS Spring OAuth Security

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, curl, oauth

I have created a Spring Security OAuth server using samples from https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

The OAuth authentication request in CURL command is as below. I want the equivalent syntax in jQuery.

```
curl -X POST -vu test-rest:test-pswd http://localhost:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=admin&username=admin&grant_type=password"
```

Here is what I tried:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token",
    method: "post",
    username: "test-rest",
    password: "test-pswd",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        "grant_type": "password",
        "username": "admin",
        "password": "admin"
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        retrieveCases();
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("authorization failed");
    }
});
```

Note: this request is a cross origin request (CORS). I have set following response headers

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, accept, x-requested-with, content-type, authorization");
```

Comment: `contentType: "application/json",` doesn't make sense. you gave it an object rather than a json string in the data option. (and you seem to need the object, not a json string.) just leave out the contentType.

Comment: you've shown us what you tried, but you didn't tell us what the result was. Did you end up with a CORS error? did it send an OPTIONS request? did it send a POST request? what was the result of each?

Comment: Your Content-Type needs to be `application/www-x-form-urlencoded`, and you don't need to create a wrapper Javascript object for the data. You just need to serialize it properly for form endcoded data type.

Comment: Yes, I get a 401 on OPTIONS

Comment: I figured out a way to allow OPTIONS request in server implementation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24492835/spring-security-oauth-stackoverflowexception

Comment: Now, I get 401 for POST request, as the user name & password combination 'test-rest' 'test-pswd' doesnt reach server

Answer (score 2):

you need to encode base 64 of  client_id + ":" + client_secret using window.btoa(str)

```js
var str = client_id + ":" + client_secret;
var enc = window.btoa(str);
var cred = "grant_type=password&username="+ userName +"&password=" + password;

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: _loginUrl,
        headers:{
            'Authorization':'Basic '+enc,
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        processData: false,
        data : cred,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('login success ...' + JSON.stringify(data));
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

OPTIONS request 401 is fixed.

I get POST 401 as username/password is not passed to server
test-rest:test-pswd

```
function authenticate() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/oauth/token",
        method: "POST",
        username: "test-rest",
        password: "test-pswd",
        contentType: "application/www-x-form-urlencoded",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        data: {
            "grant_type": "password",
            "username": "admin",
            "password": "admin"
        },
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            retrieveCases();
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("authorization failed");
        }
    });
}
```